# Google Could Firestore order string field like number

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i am trying to order a field in Firestore which is a string, but contains numbers. Can i somehow specify the ordering method or customise it?

** Edit 1:

The order i am getting is like this:

1 -> 10 -> 100 -> 101

But i want:

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4

Comment: I don't think Firestore supports what you are trying to achieve, but a workaround would be to fetch the top document and order it client side, although it might be an expensive task depending on the number of records you have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a need for strings to behave like numbers, you're using the wrong data type.  Use numbers when you need numeric behavior.  It sounds like you may have to rewrite all your documents and update your code to properly type the data.

In short, no, you can't do what you're asking (without making a change, or reordering the documents on the client).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to order items in my Firestore Recycler by querying a number value field and the app was crashing.
So i tried :

```
Query query = placesRef.orderBy( String.valueOf("likesNum"), Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(5);
```

And it worked. Although the compiler is saying `String.valueOF()` is not necessary, my problem is perfectly solved.

Maybe that helps someone with same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
query = placesRef.orderBy( String.valueOf("likesNum"), Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(5);
```

This only works because when you order by String, the limit is 9 items. Nothing will show up again after that so the best way is to store the field as a number.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the max length (total digits) of the value you're trying to sort, you can do this by adding `n` number of 0s before the value. where `n` is the max number of digits  you can have.

For example if you have 4 digits at max, then update all values as follows: 
`'1' becomes '0001'` 
`'21' becomes '0021'` 
`'100' becomes '0100'`

you'll be able to sort on query level!